# SQL -- Filling in Dates that don't have results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
Select Trunc(Create_Dtime),Count(Trunc(Create_Dtime)) as Day_0 From Player
Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(Create_Dtime) Asc
```

It gives me back dates but if a date doesn't have any results, that is skipped. I'd like to fill in all dates from 8-05-12 to present, and if those days don't have any values, just have a 0 in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to create them you can either create a [calender table](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables) or generate the rows dynamically using the Oracle [`connect by`](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html) syntax.

```
with the_dates as (
  select max(trunc(Create_Dtime)) as max_date
       , min(trunc(Create_Dtime)) as min_date
    from player 
         )
  , generator as (
  select min_date + level as the_date
    from the_dates
 connect by level <= max_date
         )
select g.the_date, count(trunc(p.Create_Dtime))
  from generator g
  left outer join player p
    on g.the_date = trunc(p.Create_Dtime)
 group by g.the_date
 order by g.the_date desc
```

If you go down the calender table option it's a little bit cleaner:

```
with the_dates as (
  select max(trunc(Create_Dtime)) as max_date
       , min(trunc(Create_Dtime)) as min_date
    from player 
         )
select c.the_date, count(trunc(p.Create_Dtime))
  from calender c
  join the_dates td
    on c.the_date between td.min_date and td.max_date
  left outer join join player p
    on c.the_date = trunc(p.Create_Dtime)
 group by c.the_date
 order by c.the_date
```

Or, having just noticed your date constraints:

```
with the_dates as (
  select to_date('07-05-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') + level as the_date
    from dual
 connect by level <= trunc(to_date('07-05-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') - sysdate)
         )
 select td.the_date, count(trunc(p.create_dtime))
   from the_dates td
   left outer join player p
     on td.the_date = trunc(p.create_dtime)
  group by td.the_date
  order by td.the_date
```

For all of these I'd recommend an index on `trunc(create_dtime)` on your `player` table.

Comment: Ben, thanks for checking into these but none of the above worked..and I'm not sure what you mean by indexing, my SQL level is quite novice. Could you possibly expand a bit more?

Comment: What didn't work? For indexes I can only suggest you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT811) or Google a bit; they're basically a quick way of accessing the table but there are many intricacies.